# Rails SQL sort by inner has_one association field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, has-one

Every User has one active account. How do i use sql to sort all Users by the updated_at field in active_account?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :active_account, -> { order('created_at DESC').where(status_code: 'active') }, class_name: 'Account'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:account).order("accounts.created_at DESC")
```

I'm not 100% sure but you might also just use the association scope, if this works this is obviously better:

```
User.joins(:active_account)
```